# Hide website elements on a window App created with electron

Tags: web-applications, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager, electron-window

I have successfully converted my website to windows app via nativefier 'mywebsite.com' how do I hide some of website elements such as header from my windows App.
Regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide some elements in the desktop app, the following js code may help:

```
element.style.display = "none"
```